# Плавный скролл страницы

Tags: jquery, javascript, frontend

Здравствуйте, уважаемые форумчане!
Есть такой вопрос, кто как делает плавный скроллинг страниц?
Сам на данный момент использую nicescroll, но не все так идеально как хотелось бы. Вот пример моей работы http://skferson.ru/

Comment: Молодец! Красиво!

Comment: Валидность страницы проверьте - есть ошибки, используйте новые теги (так как стоит доктайп хтмл5).

Comment: Тогда такой вопрос: использование новых тегов может повлиять на производительность сайта в лучшую сторону?

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/verstka-na-html5/novye-tegi

Comment: Благодарю!

Comment: @Maxim119, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

В топку ненужные библиотеки, jQuery у вас уже есть, и вот код для плавного скрола, 3 строчки:

```
$('.click-menu-element').click(function(){
       $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#elementId').position().top}, 2000);
});
```

где `click-menu-element` - это элемент меню, `elementId` - это id у заголовка нужного вам контента, находящегося в том месте, куда вам нужно переместиться (для корректировки можно уменьшить пикселей на 60), 2000 - скорость перехода на нужный элемент в мс.

[Пример тут](http://jsfiddle.net/d90vcqed/)

Внутри можно повесить также необхимый фукнционал для того, чтобы нужные пункты становились активными, ну и для определения, какой именно пункт нажал юзер. Я так понял, у вас проблемы именно с определением активного пункта меню. :)

Comment: По сути скролл по блокам я почти также реализовал, но ваш код пригодится, спасибо. )

Проблема немного в другом: как сделать плавный скролл всей страницы, когда пользователь прокручивает колесиком. Он сейчас есть, можно ускорить или замедлить, но когда прокручиваешь, глазам не очень приятно, рябит как-то.

Answer (score 1):

Чистый JS без библиотек

```
function smoothScroll(Element) {

Element = document.getElementById(Element);
var selectedPosX = 0;
var selectedPosY = 0;
while (Element != null) {
    selectedPosX += Element.offsetLeft;
    selectedPosY += Element.offsetTop;
    Element = Element.offsetParent;
}
window.scrollTo(selectedPosX, selectedPosY);
}
```

и css

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

элемент к которому тянуть

```
<button class="btn" onclick="smoothScroll('myId')">туда</button>
<p id="myId">тут</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

В нашем проекте по видеоредактированию в браузере мы скроллим таймлайн по мере воспроизведения видео. Фронтендом занимаюсь не я, но попробую объяснить, как сделали. Испытывали разные подходы, остановились на следующем:

Анимация делается CSS3 transition'ом - так плавнее всего. Длинный скролл (вам это не понадобится) бьётся на серию маленьких. Каждый следующий запускается по завершению предыдущей. Для глаза не заметно.

Comment: Интересный вариант. А можно, пожалуйста, ссылку на инфу, как делать или на пример реализации?