# Навигация страницы

Tags: jquery, навигация

Привет всем, подскажите кто знает как реализовать функционал навигации по странице как на это сайте http://pelmeni.dp.ua/.
Т.е. при нажатии на ссылку плавная прокрутка к элементу, а при прокрутке странице выделяются нужные пункты меню.

Или подскажите нужные ключевые слова для поиска
Заранее спасибо

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/372234/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B#answer-372287

Answer (score 1):

В Bootstrap есть Affix plugin, который именно это делает. Ниже пример его использования с небольшой добавкой для плавного скролла:

```js
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if(location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
        if(target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

.affix {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999 !important;
}

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.affix ~ .container-fluid {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}

#section1 {
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1E88E5;
}

#section2 {
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #673ab7;
}

#section3 {
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ff9800;
}

#section41 {
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #00bcd4;
}

#section42 {
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #009688;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#F44336;color:#fff;height:200px;">
        <h1>Scrollspy &amp; Affix Example</h1>
        <h3>Fixed navbar on scroll</h3>
        <p>Scroll this page to see how the navbar behaves with data-spy="affix" and data-spy="scrollspy".</p>
        <p>The navbar is attached to the top of the page after you have scrolled a specified amount of pixels, and the links in the navbar are automatically updated based on scroll position.</p>
    </div>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 4 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#section41">Section 4-1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#section42">Section 4-2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="section1" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 1</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section2" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 2</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section3" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 3</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section41" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 4 Submenu 1</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section42" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 4 Submenu 2</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Для просмотра примера разверните его во всю страницу.**

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение
Single Page Nav Plugin