# Как сделать мягкую прокрутку при скролле

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать мягкую прокрутку при скролле
Пример прокрутки:  http://ivanaivazovsky.life/works

Comment: По-моему похожий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/372234/279480

Comment: там по якорю скролл при клике

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов масса, но да, smoothscroll в некотором роде более универсален, потому что порой, если на странице много слоев и еще присутствует блок с fixed, то они ломают верстку. Так что берите этот вариант. Вот ссылка на гит, а так же можно просто через npm подключить https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll